# I am trying to search for a specific item in linked list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find a specific item in the list. I am sure I have made a mistake and I'm trying to figure it out. I give a specific item to look for that will be in the list but always come back with False. Need help, thank you!

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None

    def insert(self, new_node):
        node = Node(new_node) 
        current = self.head

        if self.head is not None:
            while current.next is not None:
                current = current.next
            current.next = node
        else:
            self.head = node

    def size(self):
        node = self.head
        counter = 0
        while node is not None:
            node = node.next
            counter += 1
        print("The size of the linked list is ", counter)

    def search(self, value):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node is not None:
            if current_node.data == value:
                return True
            current_node = current_node.next
        return False

    def list_print(self):
        node = self.head
        while node is not None:
            print(node.data)
            node = node.next


List = LinkedList()

elements = int(input("Enter amount of elements: "))

for i in range(elements):
    item = int(input("Item: "))
    List.insert(item)


List.list_print()
List.size()

find = input("Please enter item to search in list: ")
List.search(find)
if List.search(find) is True:
    print("Item in list")
else:
    print("Item not in list")
```

Comment: You're converting the input to `int` when you insert, but not when you search. `find = int(input("Please enter item to search in list: "))`

Comment: You don't need to call `List.search(find)` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When searching, you need to convert the input to an int first. You also don't need to check if `List.search(find) is True` you can simply use `List.search(find)`.

Here is the code:

```
find = int(input("Please enter item to search in list: "))

if List.search(find):
    print("Item in list")
else:
    print("Item not in list")
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns true if you convert your input to an int.

```
find = int(input("Please enter item to search in list: "))
```